# Version prefix used for Bech32 addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, segregated-witness

I was compiling a table for **Version prefix (hex)**  and **Base-58 result's prefix** for different types of Bitcoin addresses.

I came across the content here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes, which does not contain information about **Decimal**, **prefix Hex** for Bech32 addresses (I guess they also called SegWit address, right?)

So, I checked this chart here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/4/48/Address_map.jpg but, I don't understand the meaning of "**x03x03x00x02x03**".

1. If x00 equal 0x00 in hex and x80 equal 0x80 in hex, how should I interpret x03x03x00x02x03?
2. What is the **version** prefix for Bech32 addresses (bc1 addresses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those bytes (x03x03x00x02x03 or better shown as `0x0303000203`) are the expanded human readable part. You can find the code on [BIP-173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki).

```
def bech32_hrp_expand(s):
  return [ord(x) >> 5 for x in s] + [0] + [ord(x) & 31 for x in s]
```

The problem however is that unlike Base58 encoding, those bytes are only used in calculation of checksum *not* as the starting bytes. Which makes the picture misleading in my opinion.

Bech32 encoding is very different from Base58 encoding as there is no "version prefix". There is an Hrp, a witness version, a data (hash) and a checksum. `Witness version | hash` are the data being encoded and `expanded_hrp | data` is used in checksum calculation (`|` is concatination).

Comment: thanks for the response. I doubted the same. Upvoting and accepting the answer.